# How to get latitude and longitude of selected pixels from a raster?

Tags: raster, gdal, csv, latitude-longitude, python-3

I have have a code which will select some pixels from a raster. Further I want to get Latitude and Longitude information of these pixels and save it in .csv format.

```
import gdal
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
path="/home/vigna/Downloads/Mod_LSTS/class.tif"
img=gdal.Open(path)
array=img.ReadAsArray()
for j in range(img.RasterXSize-1):
    for i in  range(img.RasterYSize-1):       
        if array[i,j] == 4:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [GDAL and OGR utilities as library functions](http://erouault.blogspot.it/2015/10/gdal-and-ogr-utilities-as-library.html):

```
from osgeo import gdal
import os

filename='myGTiff'
inDs = gdal.Open('{}.tif'.format(filename))
outDs = gdal.Translate('{}.xyz'.format(filename), inDs, format='XYZ', creationOptions=["ADD_HEADER_LINE=YES"])
outDs = None

try:
    os.remove('{}.csv'.format(filename))
except OSError:
    pass

os.rename('{}.xyz'.format(filename), '{}.csv'.format(filename))
inDs = gdal.OpenEx('{}.csv'.format(filename))
sql = "SELECT X, Y, CAST(Z AS float(15)) AS value FROM '{0}.csv'.{0} WHERE value > 0".format(filename)
outDs = gdal.VectorTranslate('{}_filtered.csv'.format(filename), inDs, format='CSV', SQLStatement=sql)
outDs = None
```

where the GeoTIFF is converted into the XYZ format (very close to CSV). Then, the .xyz file is renamed as a .csv one and finally the desired values (e.g. `value > 0`) are filtered from the CSV file.